# How To Change Lists of Unicode to ASCII

Tags: python, list, unicode, ascii

I'm trying to change these lists I'm getting from my school grade site from Unicode to ASCII.

The lists look like this:

```
x = grades[1]
print x        #Input

[u'B', u'84']  #Output
```

But I don't want the u in there. I've tried to use

```
a.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

But I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Project.py", line 33, in <module>
    L1.encode('ascii','ignore')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

is there anyway to do this?

Comment: The "i don't want the u in there" implies a serious misconception. There is no `u` inside any of your objects. If you print out a Unicode string, store it in a file, etc., it doesn't print with the `u` any more than it (or a regular string) prints with the quotes.

Comment: im inputting it onto an image so the u shows up along with everything else

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "inputting it onto an image", but whatever you're doing, you must be doing it wrong… and "getting rid of the `u`" isn't going to help, because as long as you still do the same wrong thing, you're still going to have the extra quotes.

Comment: im drawing it onto the picture as text then making that picture my background i finished the program so it worked fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply apply the str() function to each element of your list. In python 2, str objects are ASCII encoded. For example (in a python shell):

```
>>> x = [u'B', u'84']
>>> x
[u'B', u'84']
>>> x[0]
u'B'
>>> x[1]
u'84'
>>> str(x[0])
'B'
>>> str(x[1])
'84'
```

And if a list is needed you can use a list comprehension :

```
>>> y = [str(i) for i in x] 
>>> y
['B', '84']
```

or the map function:

```
>>> z = map(str, x)
>>> z
['B', '84']
>>>
```

Hope this is what your looking for. Regards!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're trying to encode a list full of strings, not a string. You can't call string methods on a list of strings; you have to call them on each string.

The pythonic way to do this is with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> x = [u'B', u'84']
>>> y = [s.encode('ascii', 'ignore') for s in x]
>>> y
['B', '84']
```

Under the covers, this is basically the same as:

```
>>> x = [u'B', u'84']
>>> y = []
>>> for s in x:
...     y.append(s.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
>>> y
['B', '84']
```

But it's more concise, harder to get wrong, and (once you get the basic idea of list comprehensions) easier to read.

It's also the same as either of the following:

```
y = map(lambda s: s.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), x)
y = map(partial(unicode.encode, encoding='ascii', errors='ignore'), x)
```

Generally, if you need to write a `lambda` or non-trivial `partial`, a list comprehension will be more readable than a `map` call. But in cases where you have a function ready to use, `map` is often nicer.

Comment: this works fine but i there away to get just the letter and the number if not this is fine

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to convert that string `'84'` into the integer `84`? Or… what?